# Rails method returning different responses

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

When I use the truck object in the each block to call .deliveries.last, rails does not return the delivery with the highest ID for that truck.

```
@todays_workdays = Workday.todays_workdays
@todays_workdays.each do |workday|
  @working_trucks << workday.driver.truck
end
@working_trucks.each do |truck|
  if truck.deliveries.last.time_arrived.between?(Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day,Time.zone.now.end_of_day) # returns a delivery for each truck but not its actual last delivery (e.g. id 447)
    ...
  end
end
```

But when I use the Truck.find(truck.id), it works properly, returning the last delivery for each truck

```
if Truck.find(truck.id).deliveries.last.time_arrived.between?(Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day,Time.zone.now.end_of_day) # returns proper last delivery for each truck (e.g. id 486)
  ...
end
```

I'm not sure why this is happening.  Any help / explanation would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Rails 3.x ActiveRecord does not automatically order record pulled from the database-- last is not the record with the highest primary key. In Rails 4, ActiveRecord does order by primary key.

For Rails 3, try `if truck.deliveries.order(:id).last....`

I might also suggest breaking some of this logic in to scopes in your model, which are

- testable in isolation
- named in a semantic way (by you)
- chainable and therefore reusable across your codebase

[More info on scopes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes)

Comment: Thanks for your tips but I'm using Rails 4. Additionally, I tried using .sort_by{|x| x.id} and the same problem persists.